# WebService Certificate

Tags: webservices

In my sandbox I consume a webservice which needs a self signed certificate

```
WS_SGDil.ServiceSoap ws = new WS_SGDil.ServiceSoap();
ws.clientCertName_x = 'API_Client_Certificate';
return ws;
```

In the same sandbox I have this certificate
[image: picture of certificate]

Now when I callout the webservice I receive this exception

**System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: Could not find client cert with dev name: 'API_Client_Certificate' specified in clientCertName_x**

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance

Edit :
Forgot to add, I have the same call and certificate in another sandbox (for the testers). There it works. It's when I'm trying it on my dev sandbox (!= sandbox of the testers) that it fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the certificate I was trying to reach was definitely in my sandbox. Although it came from a refresh of my sandbox. Apparently .. Salesforce doesn't have a thing for created-from-refresh certs. Because I deleted the certificate, created a new one with the same name, and there it was found by my callout.

Voilà, I don't have a technical explanation, sorry... just my experience.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you have not added the certificate in the sandbox where the fallout fails. You can check this under the certificate management section in setup.

Comment: It's definitely there. It might sound unrealistic but it's there. I'm looking for a way to query for the certifcate.

Comment: Hmm. Ok - to be honest your code snippet looks good to me... sorry that I can’t help